# Jquery not working IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="de-DE">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       alert("test");
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Not working in IE8

Any hints? :(

THANKS

Mike

Comment: Problem is elsewhere... are you running this locally? Have you enabled javascript? Is it on a https page and you are blocking http requests?

Comment: Just pasted into a fiddle at jsfiddle.net and it works.

Comment: How about you give *us* a hint and describe exactly what "not working" means?

Answer (score 1):

It should works, upload your html to an online editor like [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) and test it

Answer (score 0):

IT works for me
http://jsfiddle.net/genesis/6v6JX/